# Regular Expression to find and replace repeated terms

Tags: regex, replace, repeat

I have a pile of text files that contain repeated P(m,n) terms where m and n are gradually increasing numbers. How do I find and replace re-occurring terms with Regular Expression [preferably with Funduc's Studio Pro, or Notepad ++ on Windows 7]?

Here is an example. I want to have the following text:

> P(1,1) aaa P(1,1) bbb P(1,2) bbbbb P(1,3) ccccc P(2,1) ddddd P(2,2) kkk
>   P(2,2) jjj P(2,2) lll P(2,3) rrr ....

turn into:

> P(1,1) aaa bbb P(1,2) bbbbb P(1,3) ccccc P(2,1) ddddd P(2,2) kkk jjj lll
>   P(2,3) rrr ....

Note that only first new P(m,n) terms are left, and repeating ones are replaced with a space.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to keep the first instances only, .NET's RightToLeft option comes in handy here.

Here's what I came up with:

```
(?<=\1.+)(\bP\(\d+,\d+\)\s?)
```

http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=0b5257ff-f048-45da-b7b5-39e86d69d46b

Note that this will only work in .NET (as in the Regex Hero example above) with RegexOptions.RightToLeft.

So the key part of this that makes this work is `(?<=\1.+)` which is a positive lookbehind that looks for an instance of group #1 defined in the second half of the regular expression.  And then you just replace the matches with an empty string.

---

To replace text in a bunch of files use the [Regex Hero Grep](http://regexhero.net/grep/) utility.

Comment: This would work only if you could tell me how to perform a batch operation for all my thousand html files with this method. Is there any handy free software that can perform such an operation? Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, it's like you need a .NET grep utility.  Searching around, I found a few but none have the RightToLeft option available.  I'll see if I can cook something up really quick.

Comment: @Laura - Alright, I built this in an hour so go easy on me. ;)  But I just updated my answer with a link to a .NET regex grep utility.  This should do what you want.  It doesn't have any multi-threading or anything so if you give it a really big job it'll appear to freeze as it's working through it.  But at least it supports RightToLeft.

Comment: @Laura - You're welcome.  I'm thinking this utility could be helpful for a lot of people, so I'll work on adding multi-threading support and the ability to "cancel" in the middle of an operation.  But if this answered your question, click the big check mark next to the answer.

Comment: @Laura - In case you have a use for this again, I've updated the tool to include multi-threading, progress bars, cancel buttons and such.  It's at http://regexhero.net/grep/